# Docker Compose up causes "Conflict. The container name is already in use by container"?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I found a lot of questions about this error, but none of them were specifically about using `docker compose up`.  I'd run `docker compose up` multiple times and everything works as expected, but occasionally it'll throw:

```
Error response from daemon: Conflict.
The container name "/e752d663bd1a_foo" is already in use by container "e672c49f717291b19dbad4a25a372f96b6af5c7cbe70d50d5f169adf09dcb495".
You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
```

I didn't change the Docker Compose config or start any new containers, etc. Docker should be able to identify that the container was started by Docker Compose previously, so it can reuse that container.

Here's the relevant part of my config:

```
  foo:
    image: server
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
      - connect
      - redis
    restart: always
    user: root
    environment:
      - SERVER=production
      - NODE_ENV=production
    command:
      - node
      - '--experimental-specifier-resolution=node'
      - '--no-warnings'
      - build/production/foo.js
    volumes:
      - ./env:/usr/src/env
      - ./.env:/usr/src/.env
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '1'
          memory: 2G
```

And the command I'm using:

```
node ./docker-compose.js | docker compose -f - -p foo --compatibility up -d --remove-orphans
```

Docker: v25.0.1
Docker Compose: v2.23.3

Oddly, it's always the same "foo" container that's causing the error, even though there are ~10 containers in the config.

### Edit

I removed the "container_name" field and this error appears less frequently, but I still got it a few times. Also Docker Compose sometimes recreates containers without any config changes, this might be related.

Comment: You make the host's Docker socket available to the container; is the process running code that creates containers?  The name you show in the error message doesn't match either a name Compose would generate on its own or the `container_name:` override.

Comment: This is one of the many reasons to not specify the container name. The previous container could still be deleting when it tries to start a new container. This can be resolved by removing the `container_name` line and using DNS resolution.

Comment: I'll try removing the container_name, but that seems like a workaround rather than a fix for the root cause

Comment: @LeoJiang My guess is that `container_name` is there only for backward compatibility or if you want to do something hacky but generally it should not be used. Consider you have 2 stack of 2 different apps, both has db, backend, frontend services but if you name the containers as such those will conflict if you try to run both at the same time. Also you can not scale if you use container_name: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/deploy/#replicas

Comment: @LeoJiang have you tried running and container normally like 
docker run foo mysql:8 [not with docker compose just]

Answer (score 8):

The error message shows a container name that does not match the usual naming pattern of Docker Compose or the `container_name` you have specified. That could indicate an external process or script affecting container management, leading to naming conflicts.

As per [BMitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596285/bmitch)'s [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77729821/docker-compose-up-causes-conflict-the-container-name-is-already-in-use-by-cont#comment137038334_77729821), the first test is to remove the `container_name: foo` line from your Docker Compose configuration. Let Docker Compose handle naming to avoid conflicts, especially during rapid start/stop cycles.

```yaml
services:
  foo:
    image: server
    # Removed container_name: foo
    depends_on:
    ...
```

Instead of relying on fixed container names for inter-container communication, use Docker's internal DNS service. Each service in a Docker Compose file is reachable by other services using the service name as a hostname.
See "[Networking in Compose (V2)](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)"

Given this, when you remove the `container_name` directive from your Docker Compose configuration, you should rely on this internal DNS service for inter-container communication. That means any references to specific container names within your application (if any) should be replaced with the service names defined in your Docker Compose file.

For instance, if other services in your Docker Compose setup need to connect to the `foo` service, they can simply use `foo` as the hostname, rather than a hardcoded container name.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need the `container_name` directives (Immich is an example), you can first remove the `container_name` directives from the docker-compose file, do an `docker-compose up`, then add them back and do another `docker-compose up`.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `container_name: foo` from the docker-compose yaml

You can address the containers using the service name directly.

Regarding your last point `Also Docker Compose sometimes recreates containers without any config changes, this might be related`  --> Can you add logs snippet dive further